# Declarative relationship representation based on ownership or group membership using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

A have a few tables in a Postgres database:

- `users` (users in the system)
- `groups` (groups users can be part of)
- `group_memberships` (many to many mapping of groups and users)
- `resources` (objects the users want to access)

Users can access a resource if either they own the resource or if the resource is owned by their group. Currently this is implemented with `uid` (user ID) and `gid` (group ID) foreign key columns in the `resources` table. I have a mapping already between users and groups using the group_memberships table as a secondary:

```
GroupMembership = Table('group_memberships', Base.metadata,
    Column('gid', Integer, ForeignKey('users.uid'), primary_key=True),
    Column('uid', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.gid'), primary_key=True))
Group.users = relationship(User, secondary=GroupMembership, lazy=True)
User.groups = relationship(Group, secondary=GroupMembership, lazy=True)
```

The resources are owned by either a user or a group:

```
class Resource(Base):
    # ...
    uid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.uid'), nullable=True)
    gid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.gid'), nullable=True)
    # ...
```

And the models for `users` and `groups` map back to their owned resources, e.g.:

```
class User(Base):
    # ...
    resources = relationship('Resource', backref='user', lazy=True, viewonly=True)
    # ...
```

Currently, if I want to query all resources available to the user, I combine all the resources available in `user.resources`, then iterate through all the user's groups and add those resources as well:

```
resources = user.resources + [r for group in user.groups for r in group.resources]
```

What I'd like, though, is to perform this mapping in the database instead of iterating through all the groups. It seems like this should be straightforward, but I'm not sure I understand the SQLAlchemy documentation well enough to fully map it out. Essentially what I am looking for is something equivalent to the SQL query for e.g. user with `uid=1`:

```
SELECT * FROM resources
WHERE
    uid=1 OR
    gid in (SELECT gid FROM group_memberships WHERE uid=1)
```

Any ideas how I might work this into an `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship`? Maybe my `resources` ownership model needs to be adjusted to something other than having `uid` and `gid` columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
session.query(Resource).filter(
     Resource.gid.in_(some_user.groups.gid) | (Resource.uid == some_user.uid))
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `Resource.gid.in_(some_user.groups.gid)` doesn't work.

Comment: Appreciated, but I was looking for a way to represent this relationship using the declarative relationship framework. It's easy enough to query query these things (I could even use the raw SQL I provided) but I am looking to make a bit more automatic.